# Trying to print a element from a site

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, element

i have this element : `<span class="text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render">515</span>`
and i wanna extract 515, i cant use requests and i can use selenium but that is very slow since i want it to be checked very 0,1 seconds. i tried requests but couldn't find anything on how to do it.
does anyone know how to do it? maybe beautifulsoup or other requests modules?

i tried  this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.roblox.com/catalog/20573078/Shaggy')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
mydivs = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render"})
print(mydivs)
```

but it doesn't work it just prints "[]"

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, because the tag is `<span>`, not `<a>`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.roblox.com/catalog/20573078/Shaggy'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
t = soup.find("span", {"class": "text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render"}).text
print(t)
```

Prints:

```
515
```

---

Alternatively, you can use CSS selector:

```
print(soup.select_one('[data-expected-price]')['data-expected-price'])
```